# sklearn: early_stopping with eval_set?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was using `xgboost` and it provides the `early_stopping` feature that is quite good.

However, when I look to `sklearn` `fit` function, I see only `Xtrain, ytrain` parameters but no parameters for early_stopping.

Is there a way to pass the evaluation set to sklearn for early_stopping?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean sklearn having this feature in general, or python wrapper for xgboost?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoosting`, Early stopping must be configured when you instantiate a model, not when you do `fit`.

> **validation_fraction** : float, optional, default 0.1 The proportion of
>   training data to set aside as validation set for early stopping. Must
>   be between 0 and 1. Only used if n_iter_no_change is set to an
>   integer.
>
> **n_iter_no_change** : int, default None n_iter_no_change is used to
>   decide if early stopping will be used to terminate training when
>   validation score is not improving. By default it is set to None to
>   disable early stopping. If set to a number, it will set aside
>   validation_fraction size of the training data as validation and
>   terminate training when validation score is not improving in all of
>   the previous n_iter_no_change numbers of iterations.
>
> **tol** : float, optional, default 1e-4 Tolerance for the early stopping.
>   When the loss is not improving by at least tol for n_iter_no_change
>   iterations (if set to a number), the training stops.

In order to set `early_Stopping`, you should consider passing above arguments to your model.

You may want to read [Early stopping of Gradient Boosting](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_early_stopping.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-gradient-boosting-early-stopping-py) for full explanation and examples.

Answer (score 4):

The parameter name is `early_stopping_rounds` when you call `.fit()` for `xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier()`.

Working example!

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
breast_cancer = load_breast_cancer()

X = breast_cancer.data
y = breast_cancer.target

from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 100)

GBM = XGBClassifier()
GBM.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_metric="auc",
        eval_set=[(X_test,y_test)], early_stopping_rounds=2)
```

If you intent to use the `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier()`, then you have to set the `tol` as 0 and `n_iter_no_change` as the value equal to `early_stopping_rounds`.

Note:  `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier()` does not take the seperate validation dataset, you have to feed the complete dataset and then mention the fraction of validation fraction using `validation_fraction`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [GradientBoostingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.fit)

The other answers provided here won't help if you want k-fold cross-validation and also won't help if you want the early stopping on metrics of your choice. Why?

1. Because there is no way to pass the evaluation set from outside
2. There is no provision to provide a custom metric measure

Use the following code to achieve `early_stopping` the way you are used to doing it:

```
#create a gradient booster
gbc = GradientBoostingClassifier()

#define the metric function that you want to use to early stopping
def accuracy(y_true, y_preds):
    return #return the metric output here
#This class along with the monitor argument will enable early stopping
class early_stopping_gbc():
    def __init__(self, accuracy, eval_set, early_stopping_rounds = 20):
        self.accuracy = accuracy
        self.x_val = eval_set[0]
        self.y_val = eval_set[1]
        self.best_perf = 0.
        self.counter = 0
        self.early_stopping_rounds = early_stopping_rounds
    def __call__(self,i, model, local_vars):
        for counter, preds in enumerate(model.staged_predict_proba(self.x_val)):
            if counter == i:
                break
        acc = self.accuracy(self.y_val,preds[:,1])
        if acc > self.best_perf:
            self.best_perf = acc
            self.counter = 0
        else:
            self.counter += 1
        return self.counter > self.early_stopping_rounds

#Run gradient booster with early stopping on 20 rounds
gbc.fit(X_train,y_train, monitor = early_stopping_gbc(accuracy, [X_val,y_val], early_stopping_rounds = 20))
```

This enables you to do k-fold cross validation and also use the metric of your choice